# Regex for price error

Tags: regex

Im  using the following regex code to get the price like R$ 59,00 and transform to only 59.

R\$ (\d+)
insert $$1.

However for prices above R$ 999,00, like R$ 1.000,00 there is an extra ".", and for this example the result showing is 1. instead of 1000.

Maybe its because \d only work with numbers.

Anyway, im trying to find a solution for this but i couldnt find so far.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this using regex ?

[Picture of Regex Example with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBDPM.png)

Comment: i might have a solution. Are able to do a string replace?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct `\d`will only get numbers. I don't think you can accomplish what you want with 1 regular expression.

Use `R\$ ((?:\d+\.?)+)` which would give you `1.000`
Not Sure what language you are using, but you can then replace the "." with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex:

```
R\$ [.0-9]+
```

Comment: woww almost got it. the final result was "R$ 1.000", however i need to remove the first DOT, and add an extra dot at the end, and also remove R$. So the final result should be "1000." Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: i dont think you can do that with just a regular expression.